# What is best way to connect React to a Node.js back-end

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, react-fullstack

I recently finished learning React and Node.js. I don't know how to connect the two to have a full-stack app. Can you help me with that please? What libraries are the best in which you've used?

Comment: what do you mean by connect ? you need to run the nodejs server on a local port, and then do your HTTP requests in the frontend with a library like axios or fetch

Comment: Yes. Make a server with nodejs
 and connect it user side made with reactjs

Comment: no need for a library, just use the fetch api. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Answer (score 2):

To connect the backend with the front through ReactJS, you can use axios to consume an external API, for that you install it in your application:

```
npm install axios
```

or

```
yarn install axios
```

with the backend application running locally on port 3333, for example, you can create an api.js file in your application and put the code:

```
import axios from "axios";

const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:3333/",
});

export default api;
```

So you can go to your React app's main file and consume using the useEffect hook like this:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import api from "./api";

export default function App() {

  useEffect(() => {
    api
      .get("/YOUR ENDPOINT")
      .then((response) => console.log(response.data))
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error("error" + err);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
 
    </div>
  );
}
```